# HTML Table Export

Tags: javascript, html, csv, export

I'm using the following extension to filter my table:
http://tablefilter.free.fr/
And it works fine for me, see a simple example:
https://jsfiddle.net/WcNg5/122/
I'm trying to add an export fuction for **filtered** data, luckily the author of the js script has provided such functionality (from here http://tablefilter.free.fr/doc_methods.php):
*GetFilteredData( includeHeaders ) ; 
returns an array containing only filtered data. The returned array is formated in the following manner:

•[rowindex,[value1,value2,value3...]]*
 
I'm trying to implement this, however my csv is blank with 0 bytes for some reason? Where am I wrong?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function WriteToFile() 
{
   var fso, s;
   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   s = fso.OpenTextFile("table.csv" , 2, 1, -2);
   var colvals = tf_table1.GetFilteredData();
   for (i=0; i<colvals.length; i++){
     s.write(colvals[i] + '\r\n');
 }
   s.Close();
}
</script>
<a href="#" onClick="WriteToFile();">Export Table in CSV to Desktop</a><br>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but are you testing in a browser that supports ActiveX?

Comment: Yes, IE - work. Wouldn't even download if it didn't.